# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider'

Tags: azure

I am using Redis Azure cache for session. Configure web.config

```
<add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="**.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="*******************" ssl="false" port="**" />
```

i have downloaded package from nuget but after configure web.config, it's throw error.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Installed from Nuget, I see package file in Windows Explorer, but none of the DLLs appear to have been added to the project and when I compile and run I get your error. Works if I add the references manually from their package location but why is Nuget not doing this itself? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Have you find any tag related redis in your config file? Yes I got the solution

Comment: Yes, the web.config had been updated. Just no DLLs added to the projects.

Comment: Go with Manual add dll, it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Uninstall the session state provider NuGet package
2. Delete the associated assemblies from the packages folder (e.g. solutionDir\packages\Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider*).
3. Remove all  entries from your web.config
4. Re-Install the latest NuGet package
5. Update  entry in web.config with correct values for host, accessKey, etc.

Comment: I have tried the same thing but it is not working. In my another project without any changes it is working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Have you tried hooking up to assembly load events to see where it is looking?

Comment: I have got the solution

Comment: @Neeraj :Am receiving the same error.Please suggest the solution

Comment: You did the same steps as I said in question